Server responding to request but no process listening on that port
I'm puzzled by the following situation. My Ubuntu 24.04 VPS responds to curl http://<public IP>:80 with "404 page not found", but there is no process listening on port 80 (sudo lsof -i :80), so I would expect curl to report a connection failure.
Now, when I start a dockerised Caddy server, I can bind to 0.0.0.0:80/443 fine and lsof lists the process as listening. So the system doesn't seem to think port 80 was in use, even though a different server was and is responding (see experiments below).
In addition, curling localhost vs 127.0.0.1 gives different results with a test server running (see below).
I don't really understand what is going on. Any hints appreciated. Thanks in advance!
EDIT
I did some experiments.

curl localhost:80 without sudo lsof -i :80 showing anything; returns "404 page not found"

curl <public ip as per ip -4 addr>:80 without lsof showing anything; returns "404 page not found"

curl localhost:80 with a nginx server serving a test page on port 80 (docker run -p 80:80 -v $PWD:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro nginx:latest); returns test page

curl 127.0.0.1:80 with the test nginx server; returns "404 page not found"

curl <public ip>:80 with a nginx server serving a test page on port 80 (docker run -p 80:80 ...); returns "404 page not found"

curl localhost:3000 without lsof showing anything; returns "Couldn't connect to server"

curl localhost:3000 with a nginx server serving a test page on port 3000 (docker run -p 3000:80 ...); returns test page

curl <public ip>:3000 with a nginx server serving a test page on port 3000 (docker run -p 3000:80 ...); returns test page

curl localhost:80 with a nginx test server set up with -p 127.0.0.1:80:80; returns 404

curl 127.0.0.1:80 with a nginx test server set up with -p 127.0.0.1:80:80; returns 404

curl localhost:80 with Caddy (caddy file-server --listen :80) running on the VM directly (no docker involved); returns test page

curl 127.0.0.1:80 with Caddy running on the VM directly; returns 404


The results of tests 3,6,7,8,11 are expected while 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10 and 12 don't make sense to me. Furthermore, there is some really weird behaviour that I can't explain (localhost vs 127.0.0.1 giving different results, see for example points 3 vs 4). Could the issue be on the hosting provider's side?
EDIT 2
I removed some irrelevant context from the question in an attempt to make it more concise.

May you please try the same for IP curl http://127.0.0.1:80 ? Also please check host localhost.

hi @paladin, I added some more information to the post, see point 4 for your question. host localhost returns 127.0.0.1 for ipv4 and ::1 for ipv6

Note that often with containers the port will be routed from the host  with iptables / netfilter rules to the container and then there is nothing listening on the host

hi @HBruijn, thanks for your comment. I haven't used iptables, do you have any hints what to look out for? iptables -L -n | grep 80 only returns firewall rules (ACCEPT 6 --  0.0.0.0/0 172.17.0.2 tcp dpt:80, ACCEPT  6 -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:80).

I also tried to make the question more concise since it got a down vote - I'm happy to listen to suggestions on how to make the question easier to work with

I made an educated guess do what is happening may be different. I prefer using iptables-save as normal iptables requires additional flags to show rules related to nat/mangle  which as far as I know would be where Docker and podman can create their own firewall rules to expose ports

thanks @HBruijn, iptables-save is a good tip. I did see some additional docker and kubernetes rules but to my untrained eye nothing suspicious. However, I now did a test with a caddy binary running directly on the machine without the docker network being involed, and it's the same: I can access the test page via localhost but not via 127.0.0.1 - as per @paladin 's requested test, host localhost does resolve to 127.0.0.1 though ... please also note tests 9 and 10 that I added, binding the docker server to 127.0.0.1 directly doesn't seem to work at all.

I'm tempted to wipe and reset the whole server at this point but might reach out to the provider first just to check if there is a chance something is messed up in the data centre  somehow

fresh debian image on the server and everything works, i'll leave it at that. thanks for your help, hopefully the suggestions will help others
